# need set of 8 X n.. data using <g:each> <g:if> <g:set>

Tags: html, grails, gsp

Kindly help me to define in GSP page displaying.

if i have  not fixed in set like some time i have 3 or 8 or 15 or 17
and i have the structure like
if FOR 5 sets

```
<LI>
<DIV class= A>
<DIV class=B>
<DIV class=row>
    <DIV class=col>1</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>2</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>3</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>4</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class=row>
    <DIV class=col>5</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</LI>
```

if it's 15 set then

```
<LI>
<DIV class= A>
<DIV class=B>
<DIV class=row>
    <DIV class=col>1</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>2</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>3</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>4</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class=row>
    <DIV class=col>5</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>6</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>7</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>8</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</LI>
<LI>
<DIV class= A>
<DIV class=B>
<DIV class=row>
    <DIV class=col>9</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>10</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>11</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>12</DIV>
</DIV>
<DIV class=row>
    <DIV class=col>13</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>14</DIV>
    <DIV class=col>15</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</DIV>
</LI>
```

what i am trying to do is

```
<g:set var="dataSetTotal" value="${15 }" />
          <g:set var="setDataRange" value="${8 }" />
          <g:set var="liDivCount" value="${(int)((dataSetTotal/setDataRange)+1)}" />
          ${setDataRange}
          ${liDivCount }
          <g:each in="${1..liDivCount}">
          ${it} //Run which need li section
                <g:each in="${1..setDataRange}" var="inside" status="j">
                 print ${j }
                 <g:if test="${j % 4 ==0 }">
                    print row
                 </g:if>
                </g:each>
          </g:each>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? I think, there is not so complex solution

Comment: I need to display that html format set which i mention above throgh grails tag.

Comment: Ok, you want to get chunks by 4 items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy adds a handy [collate()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html#collate%28int%29) method on Lists, which can be used as follows:

```
<g:set var="itemsPerLi" value="${8}" />
<g:set var="itemsPerRow" value="${4}" />
<g:set var="myList" value="${[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]}" />

<g:each in="${myList.collate(itemsPerLi)}" var="a">
<LI>
  <DIV class="A">
    <DIV class="B">
      <g:each in="${a.collate(itemsPerRow)}" var="row">
        <DIV class="row">
          <g:each in="${row}"><DIV class="col">${it}</div></g:each>
        </DIV>
      </g:each>
    </DIV>
  </DIV>
</LI>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Thanks andrew,Thanks a lot..head off to u..:)

Comment: Andrew,This is a little bit of understanding that is i have a set of list data.replace of number say.[[A:xyz,B:xyz,C:xyz],[A:xyz,B:xyz,C:xyz],[[A:xyz,B:xyz,C:xyz],[[A:xyz,B:xyz,C:xyz],[[A:xyz,B:xyz,C:xyz]] which i was calling from each as <g:each in="${dataSet}" var="item" status="dataCount"><div> ${item.A} ${item.C} ${item.C}  </div> </g:each>.In this we are in row which based on 4 set of data of 8.